# Sets, empty sets and set cardinality (Discrete Math)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Assume a set that has no elements, we consider it an empty set.

### Logical Questions

> Is an empty set a subset of an empty set ?
>
> If yes, does it mean the cardinality or size of the set is 0 or 1 ?

Comment: What is your definition of subset? Does it apply? Why should the cardinality be $1$?

Comment: Let $x\in\varnothing$, is it then true that $x\in\varnothing$? (If this doesn't make sense you should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)

Comment: Having something as a *subset* is different than having something as an *element*.  The empty set does indeed have the empty set as a subset despite not having any elements.

Comment: I guess I was thinking an empty set was also an element of an empty set which is not true. As you guys said, an empty set can be the subset of an empty set, but the cardinality is 0, e.g. | S | = 0 . Am I right ?

Comment: There is only one empty set, and like every set, it is a subset of itself. The cardinality of the empty set is $0$ since it has no elements. However, the fact that the empty set is a subset of itself does not "mean" that its cardinality is $0$; like I said, every set, regardless of cardinality, is a subset of itself.

Comment: yes only the number of elements are associated with the cardinality of a set.